# Unable to access variable when declared in class. Working when declared in a function. Why?

Tags: java

In the following code, `LinkedList` is a class for creating -obviously- Linked Lists and it has the method `insertFirst(..)` and `displayList()`.

I was trying to use this class to create a variable in another class --> FCFS class. Declaring it as a private variable in the class FCFS results in NullPointerException error at the lines: `process.insertFirst(..)` and `process.display()`. While when I declared it inside `work()` method it worked perfectly.

I just want to understand why this works:

```
public class FCFS {   
    public void work(){
      LinkedList process = new LinkedList();  
      process.insertFirst(3);
      process.displayList(); 
    }     
}
```

while this doesn't:

```
public class FCFS {
    private LinkedList process;

    public void work(){
        process.insertFirst(3); 
        process.displayList(); 
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second code sample, you didn't initialize `process` as you did in the first code sample.  So Java automatically initializes it to `null`, per [JLS 4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).  Use:

```
private LinkedList process = new LinkedList();
```

or you can use a constructor:

```
public FCFS() {
    process = new LinkedList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the second version, you're never initializing `process`, so it will have its default value of null. When you dereference it, you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

If you initialize `process` to `null` in the local variable version, you'll get exactly the same problem... and if you initialize `process` to a non-null value in the instance field version, it will work. It's not immediately clear *where* it should be initialized though - that will depend on the design of the rest of the class.

If you don't initialize the local variable at all, you'll get a compile-time error: while *fields* have default values (0, null, false etc), local variables don't - the compiler ensures that you don't read from a variable which isn't *definitely assigned*.

Note that if you only *need* a variable to be valid for the duration of a method - if it's not logically part of the state of the class - it would be better for it to be a local variable anyway.

Also note that Java already comes with a (generic) `LinkedList` type. I hope this code is only for academic purposes :)

Answer (score 3):

When you are declaring it in the method, you are also assigning an non-null value

```
LinkedList process = new LinkedList();
```

Inside the class, java compiler initializes the process variable with null value and hence the NPE.To resolve you need to declare the private variable as

```
private LinkedList process = new LinkedList();
```

Answer (score 1):

what kind of error you face 
is it an null pointer exception ?
try to initialize the linked list 1st

```
private LinkedList process = new LinkedList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second one you didn't initialize the LinkedList (while in the first you did). You should do this:

```
public class FCFS {
  private LinkedList process = new LinkedList();

public void work(){

  process.insertFirst(3);

  process.displayList(); 
}

}
```

or this (I usually prefer this):

```
public class FCFS {
  private LinkedList process;

public FCFS(){
  this.process = new LinkedList();
}

....(work method)

}
```

And in the code that executes FCFS,work() initialize FCFS:

```
FCFS myFCFS = new FCFS();
myFCFS.work();
```